# How to get deserialized json from url

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the URL `https://new.scoresaber.com/api/player/76561198380176668/basic` (Sorry its not formatted I don't have control of it) and i want to be able to do something in  the end like `Console.WriteLine(UserData.rank)`

I have the code I have tried here `https://hastebin.com/ogasayereh.cs`

Comment: Why you deserialize your ``json_Data`` and the result for deserialzing? can you share the value of ``Json_Data`` by updating your post?

Comment: @Sajid its in the url https://new.scoresaber.com/api/player/76561198380176668/basic

Comment: yeah, i'm adding the answer, check it, i tried this, my proposition works fine

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Ideally, you should include your code here on Stack Overflow so it's easy for people to asses the logic, and just in case the link expires in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the `json_data` is :

```
{"playerInfo":{"playerid":"76561198380176668","pp":1612.87,"banned":0,"inactive":0,"name":"sharks and shibe","country":"US","role":"","badges":"","history":"51537,51650,46246,46322,46417,46533,46591,41812,41843,41847,40630,38528,30637,15157,15091,15095,15103,15112,15117,15124,15129,15145,15144,15181,14968,11711,9905,9921,9959,7342,6974,6992,7003,7026,6887,6665,6684,6694,6721,6729,6736,6747,6763,6777,6785,6802,6799,7313,7352","avatar":"/api/static/avatars/76561198380176668.jpg","rank":7342,"countryRank":2861}}
```

1 - Then, you need to add second class like a `Root` :

```
public class RootObject
{
    public UserData playerInfo { get; set; }
}

public class UserData
{
    public string playerid { get; set; }
    public string pp { get; set; }
    public bool banned { get; set; }
    public bool inactive { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
    public string badges { get; set; }
    public string history { get; set; }
    public string avatar { get; set; }
    public string rank { get; set; }
    public string countryRank { get; set; }
}
```

2 - call the function :

```
var data = _download_serialized_json_data<RootObject>("https://new.scoresaber.com/api/player/76561198380176668/basic");
string pp = data.playerInfo.pp;
Console.WriteLine(pp);
```

I hope that will help you out.